# What's a better way to structure a React app with CRUD pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm sorry if the title doesn't make sense but by CRUD pages I mean pages like `/posts` to display all posts, `/posts/create` to display the form to create a post, `/posts/:id/edit` to display said form but with data to update

Currently, I have the following structure:

```
Post
--index.js
--form.js
--edit.js
--create.js
--list.js

hoc
--PostHOC.js
```

Post/index.js

```
import PostList from './list';

class Post extends Component {
    render() {
      <PostList posts={this.props.posts} /> // extracted from Redux
    }
}
```

Post/list.js

```
const List = ({ posts }) => {
  const postList = posts.map(post => (
    <div>
      { post.title }
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div>{ postList }</div>
  );
}
```

Post/form.js

```
const Form = props => {
  return (
    <SomeImportedForm>
      <Input defaultValue={this.props.title} /> // extracted from HOC
    </SomeImportedForm>
  );
}

export default PostHOC(Form);
```

Then `Post/edit.js` and `Post/create.js` basically just look the same (I just imported `form.js` to them, I might remove both and just the display the form and render data depending on the url)

I have googled what are good ways to structure CRUD pages with React but sadly I couldn't find any. So I opted to ask here instead. Any tips on how I can improve this? Also, I have left some code out for brevity but I believe this is sufficient for everyone to understand what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`React` doesn’t have opinions on how you put files into folders. That said there are a few common approaches popular in the ecosystem you may want to consider.

It all really depends on the level of complexity of your app, but here are a few ways to consider:

- **Grouping by features or routes** -[One common way to structure projects is to locate CSS, JS, etc inside folders grouped by feature or route.]

---

- **Grouping by file type** -[Another popular way to structure projects is to group similar files together]

---

- **Separate components into different folders depending on their role in the application** -[This is the approach I usually take and IMHO it's the best simply because as your project (hopefully) grows, you'll have a much greater sense where your main components and features are located and how everything fits together.]

Additional advice: **Don’t overthink it** -Especially not in the beginning. If you’re just starting a project, don’t spend more than five minutes on choosing a file structure. Pick any of the above approaches (or come up with your own) and start writing code! You’ll likely want to rethink it anyway after you’ve written some real code. As projects grow larger, we often use a mix of all of the above approaches in practice. So choosing the “right” one, in the beginning, isn’t very important.

Meaning, focus on the code. Good luck with learning `React` and happy hacking ;)

Comment: Hey thanks for the swift reply, but one more thing do you think I could trouble you for a github repo of what you mean by your examples? English isn't my first language and I am kind of lost by what you mean by "feature", sorry for the trouble

Comment: Your English is pretty solid, buddy. A `feature` simply means an add-on, extension, something new added to your core app structure/ functionality in order to give it a new ability (something your users or a client requested, or simply you wanted to add thinking it was cool). Look at it like this; you have a car without a spoiler, but if you add one to your car, that would be a feature :)  

Simple example [repo](https://github.com/BiggaHD/Redux_Boilerplate)
More complex example [repo](https://github.com/BiggaHD/Automated-Accountant/tree/master/root/frontend/src)

Comment: The pleasure is all mine. Accept my answer when you get the chance to. Cheers ;)